# Cargar datos desde un select option con php y ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Muy Buenas...
Estimados de antemano gracias por su colaboración y compresión ya que no soy experto.
Deseo traer los datos desde un select option dinamico el cual su data viene de una consulta a la DB mysql. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

El select option trae las empresas ingresadas previamente y de estas se escoge para traer el detalle de la información como dirección, teléfono etc. de la misma el cual se cargará en type text

1era Parte

```
<div id="contenedor">
    <form>
        <select id="cliente" onchange="CargaCliente(this.value);">
            <option>EMPRESA</option>
            <?php
            require('../terceros/conecta.php');
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM cliente';
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<option value="' .$row["cod_cliente"]. '">' .$row["r_social"]. '</option>';
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
        </select>
        <br style="clear:both;">

        <select id="idcliente"></select>
    </form>
    <div id="respuesta"></div>
</div>
<script>
function CargaCliente(val)
{
    $('#respuesta').html("<img src="" /> Por favor espera un momento");    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  'consulta.php',
        data: .serialize()+val,
        success: function(resp){
            $('#idcliente').html(resp);
            $('#respuesta').html("");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Este es el archivo para consultar.

```
    <?php
require("conecta.php");
$prove = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cod_cliente"]);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE cod_cliente = "'.$prove.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<option value="' .$row["cod_cliente"]. '">' .$row["r_social"]. '</option>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar el data del ajax a esto: `data: {"cod_cliente": val},`

Comment: @alanfcm Buen día, así como muy amablemente me sugieres, intenté pero no aun nada.

Comment: Como @alanfcm te sugiere debería funcionar, claro está si estás refiriendo al archivo PHP correcto, el que pones en `url`. Puedes hacer otras cosas, como completar tu formulario, poniendo al menos el método del mismo `<form method="post">` Y si no te funciona haz un `var_dump($_POST);` en PHP para ver qué es lo que está llegando al servidor y cómo está llegando. Y, ve modernizando tu código, en vez de `type` es mejor que uses `method` para la petición Ajax: `method: "POST",` a no ser que tu versión de jQuery sea viejísima, en cuyo caso deberías actualizarla.

Comment: Tambien puedes intentar crear un string en php y concatenar todos los options.  Luego fuera del `while` haces `echo` una sola vez con el string que creaste.